# Enclosing multiple div tags?

Tags: html, css

Mostly my issue is understanding what this step in my book is asking for. It says this word for word.

"Beneath the h2 heading, insert a new line containing a div element with the class value table at the same indent level as the previous line. Add a closing tag for the div element below the last line of store hours information. Enclose each line of code containing store hours information in a div element with the class value "row", then delete the opening and closing p tags from each line. For each line, enclose the abbreviation of the day of the week within a div element, delete the colon (:) that follows it, move the remainder of the line onto a new line, then enclose the content of the new line in a div element."

I deleted the p tags already and started putting in the div tags until I got confused on where they should be placed. Can anyone tell me where each of the div tags should be? It's due tonight and I already know my teacher won't reply before end of day because that's what college professors do best.

```css
/* 
   Spotted Wren Garden Center style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit H, Independent Challenge 1
 */

/* reset styles */
html {
   font-size: 18px;
}
article, body, div, figcaption, dd, dl, dt, ul, li, figure, footer, header, h1, h2, h3, img, nav, p, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   list-style-type: none;
}
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
}

/* global styles */
p {
   margin: 0.4em 0;
   font-size: 1.1em;
}

/* body and page container */
body {
   font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background: #6ac238;
}
.container {
   max-width: 864px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
}

/* skip navigation link */
p.skipnavigation {
   margin: 0;
}
p.skipnavigation a {
   position: absolute;
   left: -10000px;
}
p.skipnavigation a:focus {
   color: black;
   background-color: snow;
   top: 3.5%;
   left: auto;
   right: 3%;
   z-index: 2;
}

/* header section */
header {
   background-color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
h1 {
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 2em;
}
h1 img {
   display: block;
}

/* site navigation */
nav.sitenavigation {
   padding-left: 10%;
   background-color: rgb(241,90,36);
}
nav.sitenavigation li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0.4em 0.6em;
   font-size: 1.1em;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:link {
   color: yellow;
   text-decoration: none;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:visited {
   color: #ffffff;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:hover, nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
   color: yellow;
   text-shadow: 1px -1px 0 #000000;
}

/* main content */
article {
   padding: 1% 1% 1% 5%;
   text-align: left;
   background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   overflow: auto;
}
h2 {
   margin: 0 0 0.4em;
   font-size: 1.8em;
   font-weight: 700;
}
h3 {
   margin: 1em 0 0.5em;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: green;
}
figure {
   width: 40%;
   float: right;
   text-align: center;
}
.scientific-name {
   font-style: italic;
}

/* main content table */
th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.5em;
}

th {
 background-color: yellow;
}
.temps {
 background-color: #87f547;
}

.frost {
 background-color: #f5a88c;
}

/* Main Content Description List */
dd { 
 margin-left: 1em;
 font-style: italic;
}

/* Main Content CSS Table */
.table {
 margin: 1em 0;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 display: table;
}
.row {
 display: table-row;
}
.row div {
 padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
 display: table-cell;
}
.day {
 font-weight: bold;
}
/* footer section */
footer {
   padding: 1% 1% 1% 5%;
   background-color: yellow;
   clear: both;
}

/* print styles */
@media print {
   .container, h1, h2, p {
      color: black;
      background: white;
   }
   nav {
      display: none;
   }
}
@page {
   margin: 1in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Spotted Wren Garden Center - Hours</title>
      <!--
         Spotted Wren Garden Center Hours page
         Filename: hours.html
      
         Author:   Justus Self
         Date:     3/21/17
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit H, Independent Challenge 1
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.40753.js"></script>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/android.png">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <p class="skipnavigation"><a href="#contentstart">Skip navigation</a></p>
         <header>
            <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/spotwren.gif" width="864" height="184" alt="Spotted Wren Garden Center"></a></h1>
         </header>
         <nav class="sitenavigation">
   <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="hours.html">Hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="resource.html">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="consult.html">Consulting</a></li>
   </ul>
         </nav>
         <article>
            <figure id="contentstart">
               <img src="images/cone.jpg" height="301" width="200" alt="a monarch butterfly on a purple coneflower">
               <figcaption>Purple Coneflower</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <h2>Hours</h2>
   <div class="table">
            <div class="row"> <div>Mon</div> 
   <div> 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Tue: 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Wed: 8am &mdash; 5pm</div>
            <div class="row">Thu: 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Fri: 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Sat: 9am &mdash; 6pm</div>
            <div class="row">Sun: 11am &mdash; 6pm</div>
   </div>
         </article>
         <footer>
            <p>548 N. 58th St. &#8226; Omaha, NE 68132 &#8226; (402) 555-9736</p>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks to me like you mostly have it, I think you just need to drop the times under Hours down to the next line and wrap in another div.

Comment: If I do it like this it looks weird

<h2>Hours</h2>
   <div class="table">
            <div class="row"> <div>Mon</div> 
   <div> 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Tue</div>
   <div>8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Wed</div> 
   <div>8am &mdash; 5pm</div>
            <div class="row">Thu</div>
   <div>8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Fri</div>
   <div>8am &mdash; 8pm</div>
            <div class="row">Sat</div>
   <div>9am &mdash; 6pm</div>
            <div class="row">Sun</div>
   <div>11am &mdash; 6pm</div>
   </div>

Comment: Looks weird how? Anyways looks like @Sebastian has it

Comment: Yeah he got it. Thanks for your help though as well Garek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let's start with this line and follow the instructions step by step:

`<div class="row">Tue: 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>`

2. *For each line, enclose the abbreviation of the day of the week within a div element [...]*

`<div class="row"><div>Tue</div>: 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>`

3. *[...] delete the colon (:) that follows it [...]*

`<div class="row"><div>Tue</div> 8am &mdash; 8pm</div>`

4. *[...] move the remainder of the line onto a new line [...]*

`<div class="row"><div>Tue</div> 
    8am &mdash; 8pm</div>`

5. *[...] then enclose the content of the new line in a div element [...]*

`<div class="row"><div>Tue</div> 
    <div>8am &mdash; 8pm</div></div>`

Comment: That's such a weird way to do it, but I'm pretty sure that you're right. I feel like there must be an easier way to do that rather than using all of those confusing amounts of div tags.

Comment: It depends on what you have to do. For styling purposes you could just use <span> tags and surround an abbreviation of the day only.

Comment: That would make a lot more sense, but of course my book likes to keep things nice and confusing. I feel like it was written within a time frame of 4 days. Thanks for your help Sebastian.

Comment: However, your css has already defined styles for `.row div`, that is why you are asked to add divs. It should look quite nice.